# In data.table how can I supply a vector of characters to c() with some explicitly and others by reference?

Tags: r, data.table, parameterization

In a normal one off script way I have a data.table with headings:

> Date | Time | Value

Which then has the `Date` and `Time` pasted together to be parsed as POSIX later on.

The problem is in trying to parametrise (I think that's the right word) the process into a function, I can't guarantee that `Date` will always be explicitly "Date". It could easily be `date`, `DATE`, `rdate` (for some reason), or really anything.

Right now my function produces:

> Date | Time | Value | DateTime

.. but as I've mentioned, `DateTime` could easily be `rDateTime`. `Time` and `Value`are set elsewhere however, and will not change.

**EDIT** Currently the function captures the actual character string from the function inputs.

> function(hhDT, colDate = "rdate")

The *question* is:

In `setcolorder`, where the column headers are supplied as characters in the `c()` function like so:

> setcolorder(fooDT, c("col1", "col2", "col3",....))

What is the 'correct' way to supply the argument to the `c()` when it is partly known and partly user defined, **and captured in the character object `colDate`**?

i.e.

> setcolorder(fooDT, c(`colDate`, "Time", **result of paste(colDate, "Time")**, "Value"))

Where `colDate` is a character string referred to with argument colDate, and **result of ...** is the result of that pseudo code i.e. `rDateTime` or `dateTime` or `randomstringTime`.

Comment: Maybe `setcolorder(fooDT, c(grep("date$", names(fooDT), ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE), "col2", "col3",....))` or something similar

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry, just realised I omited to say that the date column is captured as a user input. Updating now.

Comment: This is kind of too broad for me. Take a look at `match.call` maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the column positions constant? if so you should use it.
If you cannot be sure they will be constant in future you can easily built in the check for `Time` position as 2nd col and `Value` position as 3rd column. If any not true just raise the error.
Do not focus on `setcolorder` but on `c` to produce expected character vector.
Your solution is almost working, you can nest `paste` inside `c`:

```
mysetcolorder <- function(DT, colDate){
    stopifnot(is.data.table(DT), is.character(colDate), colDate %in% names(DT))
    setcolorder(DT, c(colDate, "Time", paste0(colDate, "Time"), "Value"))
}
```

If it doesn't answer your question you can take a laptop for tomorrows R user group and we will make it work and update the answer :)

Comment: Brilliant. thanks for including a line for error checking too. That was something else I was trying to work out, but hadn't even asked!